# Unresloved dependency in maven

Tags: spring, maven, thymeleaf, lombok

I create new project and i have problems with 5 unsolved dependency

```
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>feelings-app</groupId>
    <artifactId>clothes-store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>clothes-store</name>
    <description>clothes-store</description>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>manager-app</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <maven.complier.source>21</maven.complier.source>
        <maven.complier.target>21</maven.complier.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.4</spring-boot.version>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and i got 5 problems:
Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:unknown'
Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:unknown'
Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:unknown'
Unresolved dependency: 'org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:unknown'
Unresolved dependency: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:unknown'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE296.png) and in project settings i have red text i dont now what change for solve this problems

i dont know what i can change